# How to check if string is numeric ignoring non-word characters?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a data frame such as:

```
Col1 

12/34/56
Hello/Goodbye
1234/7281
Bye/Hello
```

and I want to replace the numeric rows with empty spaces, like this:

```
gl.loc[gl["Col1"].str.isnumeric(),'Col1'] = " "
```

However, because there are slashes in between, python doesnt recognize the row as numeric, but I don't want to delete all the slashes from my column as they are necessary. How do I check if a row is numeric ignoring the slashes?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: Make sure to add the tag `pandas` for pandas related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.replace`.

Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['12/34/56', 'Hello/Goodbye', '1234/7281', 'Bye/Hello']})
df.loc[df["Col"].str.replace("/", "").str.isnumeric(),'Col'] = " "
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Col
0               
1  Hello/Goodbye
2               
3      Bye/Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be used to do the job.

`df.loc[df[df.Col1.str.contains("\d+?")].index] = ""`

```
print(df)

Col1
0   
1   Hello/Goodbye
2   
3   Bye/Hello
```